# How can I remove the "Python" text in my plyer notification function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using plyer to send windows notifications, but whenever I do that, there is text saying "Python" under it, is there any way to remove that? I tried using win10toast, but it seems to not cooperate with my tkinter app and causes it to freeze.

```
from plyer import notification

def download_Complete():
    notification.notify(
    title = "Youtube Utility",
    message = f"Your video, {url_title}, has finished downloading!",
    timeout = 10,
    app_icon = f"{current_dir}\\images\\main_icon.ico"
    )
download_Complete()
```

[image]

Comment: Use `win10toast`, and add option: `threaded=True`.

Comment: Have you tried setting the `app_name` parameter in your `notification()` call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can continue using `win10toast` itself if your concerned about `tkinter` freezing. It comes with a `threaded` option which is by default set to `False`. Set it to `True` and you should be good to go.